# SVG asset drawable appears blurry in android API under 23 (Marshmallow)

Tags: android, svg, scale, android-6.0-marshmallow, blurry

I've imported some icons for my app in svg format, using the Vector Asset Studio. It seems that some of the icons appear blurry when using API lower than 23. I've come to this conclusion after checking that they are blurry on my HUAWEI GRA-L09 with API 21 and on android studio emulator for Nexus 4 with API 22. 
On the other hand, Genymotion emulator for Nexus 5X with API 23 AND Android Studio emulator for Galaxy Nexus with API 23 - both displayed the icons well.
I have no idea what the problem might be - I created the resource files from local SVGs, using Vector Asset Studio, according to https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html

```
            public AllChatsAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    // create a new view
                    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.all_chats_listitem, parent, false);

                    if (!iconsInitialised){
                        mSingleChatPic = parent.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.private_chat);
                        mGroupChatPic = parent.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.group_chat);
                        mCustomChatPic = parent.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.custom_chat);
                        iconsInitialised = true;
                    }

                    return new ViewHolder(v);
            }


            @Override
            public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
                holder.mAvatar.setImageDrawable(mCustomChatPic );

            }
```

Am I missing something in the way I should work with SVGs? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find the answer?  I have the same issue

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem with some svg icons on. Use `setImageResource` instead.